# In Azure Devops, how do you select yaml pipelines when pulling from Bitbucket

Tags: git, azure, azure-devops, bitbucket

When pulling code from an Azure Devops repo you get the option to configure the build pipeline based off a yaml file:

[image: yaml pipeline]
However when using bitbucket as the repo, this same option isn't available. Is it possible to use YAML 'configuration as code' with BitBucket repos?

Answer (score 5):

You dont, unfortunately. its only supported for github and azure devops repositories (at the time of writing).

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/33037504-yaml-bitbucket-task

Comment: Still can't find a way

Comment: what cant you find?

Comment: a way to use configuration as code using bitbucket (External git)

Comment: its still not possible, as far as I know, but I dont follow Azure Devops release notes, so it might be possible now

Comment: yeah. I opened a feedback request. Glad if you want to support
[my feedback request](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/170024-additional-services/suggestions/37876549-add-yaml-support-to-bitbucket-repos-in-azure-devop)