# Azure pipelines ignoring azure-pipelines.yml from bitbucket repository

Tags: azure-devops, bitbucket, azure-pipelines

I have a `azure-pipelines.yml` file in the root of my repo, I manually trigger a build and azure pipelines dutifully ignores it.  I set the build up using the visual editor (because using bitbucket), it looks like in the past you used the visual editor to point to a custom yml file but that option no longer exists.

How am I supposed to tell Azure to use my custom .yml file?  You'd think this step would be easy...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, have seen [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54344706/in-azure-devops-how-do-you-select-yaml-pipelines-when-pulling-from-bitbucket) using bitbucket and a yaml file isn't supported.

Answer (score 0):

repoint your build to the azure-pipelines.yml or create a new one. if you dont see an option to point to another yaml file, it means this is not a yaml configurable build. create a new one that is using yaml files